# Adding Custom Animation when Removing Item RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, android-animation

I would like to show a custom animation to match the other animations that I have in my RecyclerView.  I can’t find a straight forward way of adding custom animations for removal.  I know that when RecyclerView replaced ListView one of the talking points was the ability to know when items are added or removed rather than simply saying the dataset has changed and updating everything, so I figured there would be an easy way to add an animation to a View when it is removed that I am missing.

When I add an animation to a view that is removed the animation will not play.  This is likely because the View is removed and the animation stops.  Is there an easy way to add an animation to a View that doesn’t get cut off?  I'm assuming that I could use a second thread, but I want to know if I am missing something.

```
//code for removal
holder.button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //animation to be added here on view
                list.remove(holder.getAdapterPosition());
                notifyItemRemoved(position);         
                notifyItemRangeChanged(position,list.size()-position);

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

All add/change/delete/move animations in recyclerView are made by [ItemAnimator](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/RecyclerView.ItemAnimator) (by default animator is [DefaultItemAnimator](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/DefaultItemAnimator)). So if you need custom delete animation you should provide custom `ItemAnimator` via `recyclerView.setItemAnimator(animator)` method.

I suggest to extend from [SimpleItemAnimator](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/SimpleItemAnimator) and override [animateRemove](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/SimpleItemAnimator#animateRemove(androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.ViewHolder)) method.